# Get image from fingerprint reader (delphi)

Tags: image, delphi, usb, fingerprint

How can I get the raw image from a Microsoft fingerprint reader (USB), into delphi? Is there a free component, SDK or is it possible to do it straight from delphi, with just code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GriauleBiometrics Fingerprint SDK](http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/en-us/fingerprint_sdk) is a library that may fit your needs. Supports Microsoft Fingerprint readers.

Not free, but there is a 30 day trial version.